# mongodb find distinct documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is my message collection

`{
    _id: ObjectId("dsdsdsds7878787"),
    sender: "John Smith",
    reciever: "John Doe",
    msgDateTime: ISODate("2019-09-09T17:44:24.346Z"),
    title: "hello world",
    text: "this is message body number 1"
},{
    _id: ObjectId("aaaadsds7878787"),
    sender: "John Smith",
    reciever: "John Doe",
    msgDateTime: ISODate("2019-09-09T17:44:24.346Z"),
    title: "hello world",
    text: "this is message body number 2",
    }`

when i use the below query it display (N) documents, but i need to display only one like DISTINCT in MYSQL, i don't want to repeat it n times.

```
db.message.find({sender:"John Smith", reciever: "John Doe", title: "hello world"}, {_id:0, sender:1, reciever:1, title:1}).pretty()
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for this.. You can `$group` by similar fields, then `$project` those fields to make things a little cleaner..

[You can view a live demo of this query here..](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HBSyGd3F32W)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "sender": "John Smith",
      "reciever": "John Doe",
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "sender": "$sender",
        "reciever": "$reciever",
        "title": "$title"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "reciever": "$_id.reciever",
      "sender": "$_id.sender",
      "title": "$_id.title"
    }
  }
])

// OUTPUT:
// [
//   {
//     "reciever": "John Doe",
//     "sender": "John Smith",
//     "title": "hello world"
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use `findOne()` instead of `find()`. It would return the first matched document.

**Updated query:**

```
db.message.findOne({sender:"John Smith", reciever: "John Doe", title: "hello world"}, {_id:0, sender:1, reciever:1, title:1})
```